# Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'

Tags: c#, linq

I'm getting the following error trying to group and sum some values via LINQ in EF6:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I've looked at half a dozen similar questions on StackOverflow and can't find my issue.  Here's the query:

```
var q = from c in _context.HoursProviderCosts
        where c.PatientInsuranceCompanyName == insuranceName
            && c.HoursDate >= startDate
            && c.HoursDate <= endDate
        group c by new { c.ID, c.PatientFirstName, c.PatientLastName } into g
        select new Models.InsuranceCostListItem
        {
            PatientID = g.Key.ID,
            PatientName = g.Key.PatientFirstName + ' ' + g.Key.PatientLastName,
            Total = g.Sum(x => x.ProviderRate)
        };

return q.ToList();
```

Is it something in my grouping (which I'm new to)?  The underlying EF6 model is fine (I can expand the results view of `_context.HoursProviderCosts` and look at the data just fine).

Thanks

Edit: method signature:

```
public List<Models.InsuranceCostListItem> InsuranceCostsListItems(DateTime periodStart, string insuranceName) {
```

Comment: Try using a string literal instead of a char literal: `PatientName = g.Key.PatientFirstName + " " + g.Key.PatientLastName`

Comment: @EdPlunkett AGH!  What a day...  Toss it in an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: (I blame it on JavaScript)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your space is single-quoted, so it's a character literal. [EF6 doesn't know how to translate that to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/edmx/csdl-spec#conceptual-model-types-csdl). If you use double quotes, the space is a string, and EF6 knows what to do.

```
PatientName = g.Key.PatientFirstName + " " + g.Key.PatientLastName.
```